# Publish sharepoint solution from VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm checking features for VS2012. It seems we can "publish" sharepoint solution within VS2012 directly. However, I could not find the "Publish" menu from VS2010. Is this a feature for VS2012 only?

Is there a way to do that in VS2010? It is really convenient for us to keep sync the pre-preduction if we can "publish" to remote server from vs2010.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

according to microsoft, it seems we have to manually do this in vs2010.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231526%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

2 more extra steps than in vs2012, but I can live with it.